# Como fazer uma propriedade readonly .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, propriedade

Recebi esta pergunta em uma prova e não soube responder:

"Como é possível declarar uma propriedade `readonly` em .NET / C#?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mads Torgersen (da equipa de design de C#) anunciou que esta é um feature que está a ser considerado para a próxima release (C# 6.0?).

Actualmente:

```
private readonly int x;
public int X { get { return x; } }
```

Com C# 6.0:

```
public int X { get; } = x;
```

Fonte: [Probable C# 6.0 features illustrated](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated)

Answer (score 9):

Basta usar o modificador `readonly` num campo:

```
public readonly int Numero;
```

Por exemplo. Assim, `Numero` só poderá ser atribuído um valor no Construtor da classe.

Note que não se usa `readonly` numa propriedade; Para tornar uma propriedade somente leitura, define-se seu `setter` como `private`:

```
public int Numero { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Nota: Nao e' boa pratica expor fields publicos - e' aconselhavel manter o field `readonly` privado, e usar uma propriedade get-only publica para retornar o field.

Comment: Conceitos, conceitos. Se utilizar imutabilidade direito, porque isso não seria boa prática? Uma auto-propriedade tem exatamente a mesma função de um campo público. O Encapsulamento é uma Design Pattern, não uma Good Practice. O mundo não gira em torno de Orientação a Objetos -- não o tempo todo.

Comment: Nao se trata so de imutabilidade. Hoje compilas uma assembly X que depende da assembly Y, e le um field publico "Numero" de Y. Amanha, decides adicionar logica e mudar o field "Numero" para uma propriedade "Numero". A assembly X agora vai crashar.

Comment: Jon Skeet apresentou mais um milhao de razoes [aqui](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx). Quebra a assembly, quebra a capacidade de usar reflection, ja nao pode usar `ref` ou `out`, etc etc. Os fields devem ser (*quase*) sempre privados.

Comment: Bom ponto, mas não se encaixa com Read-Only, eu diria. Se eu fosse usar valores mutáveis, eu certamente iria expor uma auto-propriedade no lugar de um campo.

Comment: Porque nao? Voce hoje tem um readonly field, mas amanha pode querer encapsular a leitura do field com alguma logica extra, tipo `Logger.Log("O campo foi lido 1 vez"); return _numero;`. Entao vai ter que encapsular o field numa propriedade (get-only). Ai vai quebrar tudo.

Comment: Esse é um caso específico. Na maioria dos casos, mudar o tratamento de uma propriedade pode causar mudanças indesejáveis nas dependências; Quem saiba eu não queira sempre Logar o campo, por exemplo? O ideal seria adicionar uma nova propriedade get-only que Loga e depois retorna o campo.

Comment: @dcastro Como nota, eu acho que no C# 6, auto-propriedades somente-leitura são uma boa alternativa a campos privados. Mas infelizmente ainda estamos no C# 5 no tempo desta pergunta, que refere-se explicitamente a campos e à funcionalidade da palavra-chave `readonly`.

Comment: O logger foi so um exemplo, mas eu so queria demonstrar que e' possivel (e muitas vezes provavel) que fields venham a ser encapsulados em propriedades, readonly ou nao, por diversas razoes. E, como tal, devemos programar defensivamente e pensar no futuro. So para clarificar: eu concordo com o resto do post, a resposta esta' correcta, e dei +1 ;)

Comment: @dcastro Também concordo com a sua que está ganhando da minha graças a meu upvote, no momento deste comentário xD Entendo que temos que pensar no futuro. Só tenho estudado programação funcional e vi que campos imutáveis são uma aproximação rápida a classes imutáveis.

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi dar uma resposta mais moderna, até porque as respostas atuais são contestáveis ou estão erradas.

A pergunta não é muita clara no que deve se extender somente leitura. Se ele deve ser assim só publicamente a resposta com `private set` está correta. Caso contrário, está errada.

Se a propriedade de ser somente leitura, mas o campo não, então basta não usar o `set`, mas não pode ter o `readonly` no campo. Imagino que o mais certo aí é que a propriedade e o campo não possam ser alterados, depois de inicializados.

Nenhuma resposta fala ou demonstra a inicialização. Então estritamente elas são um problema. Em versões antigas do C# (até a 9) só dava para inicializar de verdade no construtor. Note que a resposta aceita inicializa com uma variável que nem existe, e se for um campo, não sabemos se ele tem um valor, se é inicializado, nada. Deveria ser algo assim (pelo menos desde a versão :

```
public Classe(int x) => X = x;
public int X { get; }
```

Não faz mais sentido falar em C# 5, mas se precisar dele teria que definir o `get` pegando o campo manualmente e teria que declará-lo separado, ou seja, não pode fazer *auto property* sem `set`.

Mas em C# 10 podemos fazer sem construtor, na maioria das situações:

```
public int X { get; init; }
```

Mas isso pode ser um problema. No C# 11 podemos fazer o que provavelmente é o mais certo:

```
public required int X { get; init; }
```

Assim permitimos a inicialização, ou até mesmo obrigamos ela. Sem uma dessas três formas não é somente leitura, na prática é uma constante.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/ReadOnly.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma é criar um propriedade sem o `Set`

```
public int PropriedadeReadOnly
{
    get { return propriedadeReadOnly; }
}
```

E uma segunda forma, que permite que a propriedade seja escrita somente uma vez, geralmente no construtor de uma classe. É usando `readonly`

```
public readonly PropriedadeRead;
```

Answer (score 2):

Para colocacar uma proriedade com somente leitura, temos duas opções, colocar somente o get na declaração da propriedade ou declarar o set como privado.

Answer (score 0):

No caso do VB net, você pode escrever assim:

```
Public ReadOnly valor_pi as Single = 3.1415
```

Comment: OP perguntou especificamente em C#.

Comment: Puts, eu passei por isso despercebido uahuahu Valeu ;D

Answer (score -1):

Se quer uma propriedade readonly faça ela ter apenas o Get, por exemplo:

public int MeuInteiroReadOnly { get; }

Isso fará com que essa propriedade só possa ser definida no construtor da sua classe, que é o comportamento de um campo readonly.

Isto é diferente de ter um set privado, onde qualquer método da classe poderia alterar o valor da propriedade e não só o construtor.

Então public int MeuInt{get;} é diferente de public int MeuInt{get;set;}

Se quer readonly usa a primeira opção.

P.S: Sei que esse post é antigo, mas pode ser que a resposta ainda ajude alguém que possa estar procurando uma ajuda parecida. ;)